# Flutter : the two container radius has a small line shadow

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, containers, border-radius

[image]

Now I am trying to draw a container with the radius border to intersect with another container
But there is a line that remains visible around each container as shown in the picture Does anyone know how to hide it!

there is my code for that

```
Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .47,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(28, 163, 200, 1),
                border: null,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  //bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(28, 163, 200, 1),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 250, 251, 1),
                    border: null,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                      //bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "القائمة",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Text(
                          "عرض الكل",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 140, 0, 1)),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the hight of the container it will render correctly. I have attached a screenshot of the result I get with this:

```dart
Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 300, //<--- This is what's causing the issue
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(28, 163, 200, 1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                //bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            // color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(28, 163, 200, 1),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 250, 251, 1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    //bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "القائمة",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Text(
                        "عرض الكل",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 140, 0, 1)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a renderer artifact, if you change the top container height ratio it goes away

```dart
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .47, // <-- change this to be 0.5
```

if you really want that particular height, then use a `Stack()` rather than embedded Containers

Comment: height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .47, // <-- change this to be 0.5 .. this solution doesn't work for my case , i will try the stack and back for you

Comment: Check my updated answer with a screenshot. Fractional dimensions are always the cause of this kind of renderer behavior. sometimes it fails in a fraction of a pixel which is hard to render without bleeding!